# Find my iPhone email on login

Tags: find-my-iphone

Before, Apple would send an email when my Apple ID was used to login to Find my i
iPhone on another device. Did Apple take away the email notification when your Apple ID is used to login to Find my iPhone?

Comment: The email arrives when you log into an appleid from an unrecognized device, or if you play a sound, or set lost mode from findmyiphone.  Logging on from a "recognized" device and tracking the iPhone via findmyiphone will not generate an email.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you now just can look over the connected devices when you wish at:

- https://www.icloud.com/#settings

The mails are still sent when you remove a device, but I don't recall getting the sign on ones anymore.